# Zurb Foundation 6: dropdown buttons and links aren't working

Tags: html, button, zurb-foundation, dropdown

I have downloaded the foundation 6, the zipped folder comes with foundation.js, foundation.min.js jquery.js, foundations.css, foundation.min.css. I try to implement dropdown buttons, but, they're not working and i don't know why.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/foundation.css"/>
        <script src="../js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>$(document).foundation();</script>
        <button href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" aria-controls="drop1" aria-expanded="false" class="button dropdown">Dropdown Button</button><br>
        <ul id="drop1" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown" aria-hidden="true">
            <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

I really don't know why this not work. Please, help me!

(note: the dropdown code above was extract from the oficial documentation site http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/dropdown_buttons.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are using code relevant to foundation 5.5.3, but on the foundation 6 core files. check this link for reference: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/button.html

Also check your developer tools if foundation.min.js is loading and no errors in console.

Comment: Yeah, I saw. My problem was solved. I got help in zurb foundation Forums. My objective was to create a multi page website with zurb, but, i've learned to do this alone, just testing some things in my code. Anyway, Thanks for the help.